# PayPal API create invoice on behalf 3rd party

Tags: paypal

I have a site where my clients select a service to buy, but an other department will pay for them. so the idea is when the client confirm to buy an item, paypal will send an invoice to the payment department, once the payment done, paypal should notify the seller and buyer that the payment has been made, then the application authorize the client to use the service.

Does anyone know if there is PayPal API that can handle this workflow?
or any other idea please?

Comment: Use paypal Invoicing API.

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/ht_permissions-invoice/) to find out how.